# Scraping The Lego Movie on IMDb using rvest in R

Tags: r, rvest

I'm learning `rvest` 0.3.1 package.

Using the code from **[this tutorial](http://stat4701.github.io/edav/2015/04/02/rvest_tutorial/)**, I only changed `html` to `read_html`

```
library(rvest)
# Store web url
lego_movie <- read_html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")
#Scrape the website for the movie rating
rating <- lego_movie %>%
  html_nodes("strong span") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.numeric()
rating 

# Scrape the website for the cast
cast <- lego_movie %>%
  html_nodes("#titleCast .itemprop span") %>%
  html_text()
cast
```

However, rating and cast just return

```
numeric(0)
character(0)
```

Any suggestions how to fix this would be appreciated?

**UPDATE**

I'm using `rvest v0.3.1` and `xml2 v0.1.2` on `R 3.2.3` but still rating and cast return

```
numeric(0)
character(0)
```

[image]

Below is running the code step by step

```
rating <- lego_movie
rating
{xml_document}
<html>
[1] <head>\n    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>\n    <title>\n      Web Filter Block Override\n    </title>\n    <style type="text/css"><![CDAT ...
[2] <body class="authenticate">\n    <div class="header">\n      <h2>\n        Powered By Fortinet\n      </h2>\n      <h1>\n        FortiGuard Web Filtering\n      </h1>\n    </di ...
rating <- lego_movie %>% 
   html_nodes("strong span")
rating
{xml_nodeset (0)}
rating <- lego_movie %>% 
   html_nodes("strong span") %>%
   html_text()
rating
character(0)
rating <- lego_movie %>% 
   html_nodes("strong span") %>%
   html_text() %>%
   as.numeric()
rating
numeric(0)
```

Comment: You code works for me

Comment: @Symbolix
Thanks for taking the time to try it. Why do you think it is not working with me?

Comment: has `xml2` correctly installed?

Comment: @Symbolix
I installed it as other packages install.packages("xml2"). Is there a specific way to install it?

Comment: not that I know of, I was merely guessing that it **could** be an issue.

Comment: Can you break your problem down into stages: does `lego_movie` contain anything?

Comment: your code also works for me (same versions, on Mac)

Comment: I tried the code above on another PC and it worked fine. However, I'm still getting the same result numeric(0) and character(0) if I run it on my PC. Any suggestions how to fix that

Comment: @Symbolix
On my PC, lego movie contains the follwing {xml_document}
<html>
[1] <head>\n    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>\n    <tit ...
[2] <body class="authenticate">\n    <div class="header">\n      <h2>\n        Powered By Fort ...

Comment: @aelwan and the next line...?

Comment: Sorry, by 'the next line', I meant the `lego_movie %>%
  html_nodes("strong span")` bit

Comment: @Symbolix 
Thanks. I misunderstood it. Please, check the update.

Comment: Have you used the selector gadget (in the tutorial you've linked to) to double-check the `strong span` rating element exits?

Comment: @Symbolix 

Yes, I did. Please, check this link https://goo.gl/OSBeBL

Comment: The code is working fine now just by adding this line before the code

Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http_proxy=http://tur-cache2.massey.ac.nz:8080/ http_proxy_user=ask")

Comment: Glad yo got it sorted. You should add an answer.

Comment: @Symbolix
I'll add it. I can't thank you enough for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code worked just by adding the line below at the start

`Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http_proxy=tur-cache2.massey.ac.nz:8080 http_proxy_user=ask")`

Answer (score 2):

Using `rvest v0.3.1` (and `xml2 v0.1.2`) on `R 3.2.3`, the code you've used should work. Here's a screenshot of it working in my environment

[image]